# Connecting database locally using MAMP

Tags: php, mysqli, mamp

I am using this code to connect:

```
     require_once('db_credentials.php');

     function db_connect() {
         $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
             return $connection;
            }

  function db_disconnect($connection) {
      if(isset($connection)) {
      mysqli_close($connection);
    }
  }

 ?>
```

here is my db_credentials.php file:

```
  <?php

  define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
  define("DB_USER", "");
   define("DB_PASS", "");
  define("DB_NAME", "globe_bank");
```

I use a simple assoc statement to show my table called subjects, but I get no display at all on the website.

I think I might have written wrong infomation in my db_credentials

I have a screen shot of the information of my database: [image]
      ?>

I created an user called hej with the password 123, and the user has been granted all access.

This is my index file where I'm trying to show my table called subjects:

```
 <?php require_once('../../../private/initialize.php'); ?>

       <?php

     $subject_set = find_all_subjects();

     ?>

     <?php $page_title = 'Subjects'; ?>
      <?php include(SHARED_PATH . '/staff_header.php'); ?>

      <div id="content">
        <div class="subjects listing">
          <h1>Subjects</h1>

          <div class="actions">
            <a class="action" href="<?php echo url_for('/staff/subjects/new.php'); ?>">Create New Subject</a>
</div>

<table class="list">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Visible</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>

  <?php while($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subject_set)) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo h($subject['id']); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo h($subject['position']); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $subject['visible'] == 1 ? 'true' : 'false'; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo h($subject['menu_name']); ?></td>
      <td><a class="action" href="<?php echo url_for('/staff/subjects/show.php?id=' . h(u($subject['id']))); ?>">View</a></td>
      <td><a class="action" href="<?php echo url_for('/staff/subjects/edit.php?id=' . h(u($subject['id']))); ?>">Edit</a></td>
      <td><a class="action" href="">Delete</a></td>
      </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>

<?php
  mysqli_free_result($subject_set);
          ?>
        </div>

      </div>

      <?php include(SHARED_PATH . '/staff_footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: *I think I might have written wrong infomation in my db_credentials* - Consider putting the right credentials or at least confirm your suspicion before you post a question to make it easier for us?

Comment: Well The credentials I have used is what I thought to be the correct ones, but since I'm getting no input I suspect I could have misunderstood what are the correct credentials to use. (That's why I included the screenshot and the user infomation, in case I have misunderstood it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When connecting to `localhost` the user credentials by default (unless changed) are either a combination of the following:

```
root/root
root/
```

Where the first value is the username and second value is the password.

**Note:** The second password value is intentionally left blank to signify an empty string.

Comment: I included my index file, however I still suspect I have misunderstood using mysql correctly as I just started to learn about it today..

Comment: I missed a syntax after writing root/root. 
Thank you for the help!